# Xlwings / open password protected xlsx?

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

is there any way to open a password protected excel-sheet with xlwings?
(whole xlsx is protected - that means when the excel is opened you have to put in a password to get to the excel)

If not is there any other way to protect the excel-sheet for some users - but have access with xlwings to the worksheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`xlwings.Book()`](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#book) has a `password` parameter:

> password (str) – Password to open a protected workbook

You should just be able to

```py
import xlwings

wb = xlwings.Book("file.xlsx", password="Passw0rd!")
```