# Xlwings / open password protected worksheet in xlsx?

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I get an answer how to open a password protected xlsx with xlwings:
[Xlwings / open password protected xlsx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71228348/xlwings-open-password-protected-xlsx)

```
wb = xlwings.Book("file.xlsx", password="Passw0rd!")
```

But can i also open and handle a worksheet in an xlsx - where only this specific worksheet of the xlsx is password-protected and not the whole xslx?
Or the xlsx is only password-protected for writing (and reading is allowed)?

I tried this with the solution from the above link but this didn´t work for the situations as desccribed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Protect Sheet'.

```
ws.api.Protect(Password='test')
ws.api.Unprotect(Password='test')
```

Other features under this setting (not full tested);

```
ws.api.Protect(Password='test', DrawingObjects=True, Contents=True, Scenarios=True,
        UserInterfaceOnly=False, AllowFormattingCells=False, AllowFormattingColumns=True,
        AllowFormattingRows=False, AllowInsertingColumns=False, AllowInsertingRows=False,
        AllowInsertingHyperlinks=False, AllowDeletingColumns=False, AllowDeletingRows=False,
        AllowSorting=False, AllowFiltering=False, AllowUsingPivotTables=False)
```