# How to append to a spreadsheet with python script but protect the data from being manipulated by others

Tags: python, database, openpyxl

I have a program that writes in sensor data to a spreadsheet via python script, but I don't want anyone to be able to accidently manipulate the data if they open the spreadsheet themselves. The only thing that should be able to edit the spreadsheet is the program when it is appending data. There does not seem to be anything obvious in the openpyxl module website that would help me. I am open to alternatives and maybe even changing things around to work with databases if necessary. thank you

Comment: Then why not just write a PDF file?  Why make it a spreadsheet?  You CAN use "cell protection" to make some regions read-only.

Comment: This software is being used to log sensor data of a unit for functionality, essentially quality checking each unit. This spreadsheet will grow to have thousands of units on it. I am not sure if producing a single or multiple pdf's is good for something that constantly has data appending to it. Plus being able to then do statistical analysis of the data in needed which is why the spreadsheet is a good option.

Comment: If you are able to use Xlwings (Excel installed locally) it is able to apply the sheet protection see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71267540/xlwings-open-password-protected-worksheet-in-xlsx/71295385#71295385. Openpyxl has limited capability to apply.